# rails4 choose existing files from images directory or upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip gem to allow an user to upload images and associate it to a product, everything works fine, now I would like also allow the choice from existing images saved in app/assets/images by me... Actually  I have this in product controller:

```
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :amount, :volume, :user, :avatar)

end
```

end

this in product model:

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :avatar, 
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type 
    => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    end
```

and this in new/edit form:

```
<%= form_for(@product)  do |f| %>
<% if @product.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this
product from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :price %><br>
<%= f.text_field :price, :value => (number_to_currency(f.object.price, 
:precision => 2) || 0) %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :amount %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :amount, :value =>  
 (number_with_delimiter(f.object.amount, :precision => 2 || 0)) %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :volume %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :volume,  :value =>   
 (number_with_delimiter(f.object.volume, :precision => 2 || 0)) %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :choose_a_logo %>
 ???
 <%= f.label :or_upload_your_image %>
 <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
 </div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>


<% end %>
```

Someone can help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

add "simple_form" and 
    "paperclip" gem to your gem file 
run

```
$ bundle install
```

now run these two commands

```
$ rails g simple_form:install
```

or in order to integrate with bootstrap run

```
$ rails g simple_form:install --bootstarp
```

next step run

```
$ rails g paperclip modelname xyz
```

**modelname** should be replaced by the model name you want to be associated with
**xyz** should be replaced by the name user should call it most common convention is 'image'  but in your case its avatar

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

next step go to app -> models -> modelname.rb(paticular model you want image to be associated with same one as above)
copy this before <% end %> in file 
............

## association

has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {medium: "320x240>"}

## validation

```
validates_attachment :avatar, presence: true
```

## optional if you want to specify input

```
  ,content_type: {content_type: ['avatar/jpg','avatar/jpeg']}
```

................

## please replace your **form_for** **simple_form_for** displaying at the top of your form view file

update your form's **new** ("where you want to give the option of upload ")
example (<%= f.input :name %>)

```
<%= f.input :avatar, label: "bla bla" %>
```

update your form's **show**
get rid of this whole thing 
.......................

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :choose_a_logo %>
 ???
 <%= f.label :or_upload_your_image %>
 <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
 </div>
```

.......................
 replace with

```
<%= image_tag @modelname.avatar (:medium)%>
```

.........
all set but this will only work if image magik is installed ... 
check it by running the following command in your terminal

```
$ which convert
```

if it returns with

```
$ /user/bin
```

or

```
$ /user/local/bin
```

congratulation but if not go and install image magic first

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip is used for loading the images from the local machine to the rails app.

If the rails app is on the local machine, you should be able to navigate to `app/assets/images` and upload them to the specific object.

If you want to provide this functionality on the server, you will have to build a separate screen to populate all the images from `app/assets/images` folder and add the link to use those images.

The second option there is a development heavy task; make sure it is exactly what you want before trying to build it.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Uploading images in app/assets/images works fine simply adding them before push on heroku (it's a little number of images, does not create problems) I don't know how allow user to chose from them... Does exist a gem (or a tutorial) for this? It's a crucial part for my app... Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: That is not a very common use case; I doubt if there will be any standard tutorial / gem for it. You'll have to dig in and figure out how to do it yourself.